# Show size of attached file in AEM forms guidefileuploader component

Tags: forms, file, aem, attachment, uploader

I'm trying to get (and show to the user) the size of each file attached to a form using guidefileuploader AEM forms core component.
[AEM Forms (PDF Type) File Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882616/aem-forms-pdf-type-file-attachments/68005376?noredirect=1#comment120198583_68005376)

Any help in overriding/extending this component or any hint please?